# Is it possible to change the log level of a package in log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Currently I have a library that is logging certain information as ERROR. If I change my log4j settings like this:

```
log4j.logger.com.company.theirpackage.foo=OFF
```

that will completely disable the library's logging altogether. However, what I'd really like is to still see the information, but have it logged at a WARN or INFO level. In other words, when that particular code calls `log.error()`, I want it to be as if they had called `log.warn()` or `log.info()` instead.

Is there a way to do this with log4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but you could write a custom appender that intercepts the calls, checks the levels, and then prints them at whatever level you want. Or, you could do some aspect oriented programming and intercept/change their calls.

But why would you want to change the level they log it at?

Comment: Our service treats an ERROR as a really bad event, whereas this library logs all sorts of unimportant things as ERROR. I could change our log monitoring to ignore ERRORs from this package, but I'd rather this library just not log such unimportant things as ERRORs.

Comment: Got it. Are you using any application frameworks like Spring? They make aspect weaving pretty easy.

Comment: @JeffStorey You you please elaborate or provide an example for this? I have the similar requirement

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible, by implementing a [Filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html), in which the level inside a [LoggingEvent](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html) is changed when it matches certain conditions.

Comment: Can you change the level? I didn't think you could.

Comment: There isn't a setLevel() method, but you can use reflection to set the field directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that. I think the easiest way to do that is to use custom Appender.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="console-> %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <Console name="CUSTOM_ERROR_STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="dependent-> %-5p{ERROR=WARN} %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- Root logger referring to console appender -->
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>

        <Logger name="com.my.LogTest" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="CUSTOM_ERROR_STDOUT" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here I convert all the **error** logs into **warning** for that specific class **com.my.LogTest**. You can find more info about Appender Layouts [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html). It has pattern selector option which allows you to choose different pattern based on your condition.