# Downcast log level in Log4j from error to warning

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using a library making use of log4j. This library sometimes writes [error ] logs. However, I would like to change those errors to warnings without changing the source code of the library. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the log level of a package in log4j?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060362/is-it-possible-to-change-the-log-level-of-a-package-in-log4j)